# How to make github (facing issue while getting result) example in fiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, i18next

I am making the given example on fiddle .It is not working on fiddle I want to use i18next .so that my text will change when user change the language
so I found this solution 
https://github.com/tabacha/javascript-i18n-example

Use this on fiddle .I drop all js in dropbox and use that link in external resource but that functionality not work for me.
Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dWq4E/1/

```
var text = document.getElementById("text").firstChild,
 title = document.getElementById("title").firstChild,
 instruction1 = document.getElementById("instruction1").firstChild,
 instruction2 = document.getElementById("instruction2").firstChild,
 num = document.getElementById("num"),
 lang = document.getElementById("lang");

i18n.init(function(t) {


title.nodeValue = i18n.t("title");
text.nodeValue = i18n.t("ball", { count: 2 });
instruction1.nodeValue = i18n.t("chooser.ball");
instruction2.nodeValue = i18n.t("chooser.lang");

});
num.onchange = function (e) {
  var t =i18n.t("ball", { count: parseInt(num.value) });
  text.nodeValue=t;

};

lang.onchange = function (e) {
   i18n.setLng(lang.value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues why the code is not working. The best way to figure out what is going on is look in the console. In your browser, press F12 for the developer tools. Chrome/Firefox and IE10+ have the best tools.

The first issue is that Dropbox is not a good place to host web files. When you are making a request for that file it is actually returning all the html to render the page as you see it if you go to the url. So it is not valid JavaScript. You really need some proper webspace to test this, or you can do it locally using web server (IIS,Apache,XAMP etc)

[image: Error]

There are no elements in the HTML with an id of "text" or "title" so the code for `document.getElementById("text").firstChild` and `title = document.getElementById("title").firstChild` returns null, which means later code to set i18n text fails.

The closest I could get his to work in a [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dWq4E/2/) but I can't set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on my hosting space to allow cross site json request.

There is a demo page on my hosting for you to see it working: http://www.forward-slash.co.uk/demo/i18ntest.htm

HTML:

```
<p id="text">Should be set by js</p>
<p id="title">Should be set by js</p>
<p id="instruction1">Should be set by js</p>
<input id="num" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="2" />
<p id="instruction2">Should be set by js</p>
<select id="lang" size="1">
    <option>select language</option>
    <option value="de">German</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
// location of the translation files go here
i18n.init({ resGetPath: '/lib/__ns__-__lng__.json.txt' });

var text = document.getElementById("text").firstChild,
    title = document.getElementById("title").firstChild,
    instruction1 = document.getElementById("instruction1").firstChild,
    instruction2 = document.getElementById("instruction2").firstChild,
    num = document.getElementById("num"),
    lang = document.getElementById("lang");

i18n.init(function(t) {
    title.nodeValue = i18n.t("title");
    text.nodeValue = i18n.t("ball", { count: 2 });
    instruction1.nodeValue = i18n.t("chooser.ball");
    instruction2.nodeValue = i18n.t("chooser.lang");
});

num.onchange = function (e) {
  var t =i18n.t("ball", { count: parseInt(num.value) });
  text.nodeValue=t;
};

lang.onchange = function (e) {
   i18n.setLng(lang.value);
   // it appears the above sets a language cookie with the selected language
   // we can refresh the page for the correct translations, but e need to put in
   // a bit of a delay to allow the cookie to be set
   setTimeout("location.reload(true);",500);;
};
```